# Verb for checking works before allowing publication

Tags: word-request, verbs

In any undemocratic country any news must be checked again and again before they can be printed, so what verb should i use to describe the process of checking sth, expecially for news,books ect. and could you give me a revelant example?

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends. "Check" has several meanings.

Do you mean the news story has to be checked for errors (editing)?

Or do you mean the information in the story has to be checked for accuracy (researching)?

Or do you mean that the story has to go through the censors before it can be printed (approved)?

Comment: The question specifically refers to checking "before they can be printed". It also refers to undemocratic countries, so "accuracy" is hardly the issue. The answer is "censorship".

Answer (score 0):

I think [proofread](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proofread) can be used here.

Comment: Absolutely not. Proofreading is primarily about checking spelling, grammar, punctuation etc. Proofreading does not necessarily involve fact-checking. And it is a completely different thing from the phenomenon mentioned in the quest, where undemocratic countries screen things for politically acceptable content prior to allowing publication.